# MVC Form: align Actionlink and button next to each other on same vertical alignment

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using the same css class for my button and actionlink, however they're not aligned properly. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ez1v.jpg

Here is my code:

```
@model MyModel

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "DossierForm", data_validate_form = "" }))
{
<div id="DDetails">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.WarningMessage)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ErrorMessage)
    @...

    <div style="display: inline;">
        @Html.ActionLink("cancel", null, null, new { @class = "button button--secondary" })
        <button id="submitbutton" value="save" title="save" type="button" class="button button--secondary">save</button>
    </div>
</div>

}
```

What can I do to put the button and actionlink on the same height?

Comment: Share your rendered html and related css

Answer (score 0):

Putting the button and actionlink in a div with `display: inline-flex; vertical-align:top"` did the trick:

```
<div style="display: inline-flex; margin-right: .5em; vertical-align:top">
    @Html.ActionLink("cancel", null, null, new { @style = "margin-right: 5px;", @class = "button button--secondary" })
<button id="submitbutton" value="save" title="save" type="button" class="button button--secondary">save</button>
</div>
```